# Jurabib footcite inside figure

Tags: graphics, floats, jurabib

I'm currently trying to place a footnote inside the caption of a figure. It looks like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{images/trust_stats}
    \caption[Online Privacy]{Suvery on Online Privacy \footcite{stats:privacy}}
\end{figure}
```

Here is my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \begin{filecontents}{\quellen.bib}
@www{some:source,
    author="some author",
    title="some title",
    year="2010",
    url="some url",
    urldate="09.03.2017"
    }
\end{filecontents}
    \usepackage[ibidem=strict,commabeforerest,see,
    titleformat={all,colonsep,italic},
    authorformat={year},
    pages=format
    ]{jurabib}

    \def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
    \usepackage{amssymb}

    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{float}
    \brokenpenalty = 10000 

    \begin{document}
            \section{Lorem ipsum}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            \begin{figure}[H]
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=14cm]{images/trust_stats}
                \caption[Stats Online Privacy]{tats Online Privacy\footcite{some:source}}
            \end{figure}
            \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

        \bibliography{quellen}

    \end{document}
```

Here is the entry in sources:

```
@www{some:source,
    author="some author",
    title="some title",
    year="2010",
    url="some url",
    urldate="09.03.2017"
    }
```

But I don't get a proper footnote with text at the bottom of the page. As the title suggests I am using Jurabib to manage my sources.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Please make a compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). Please consider that we don't have `settings.tex` nor your image.

Comment: I edited it, settings.tex is not relevant nor is the chosen image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bobyandbob Ansatz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/357322/36296) with using `\footnotemark` works fine in combination with `\footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{some:source}}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\input{settings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[ibidem=strict,commabeforerest,see,
titleformat={all,colonsep,italic},
authorformat={year},
pages=format
]{jurabib}

\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\brokenpenalty = 10000 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@www{some:source,
    author="some author",
    title="some title",
    year="2010",
    url="some url",
    urldate="09.03.2017"
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
      \section{Lorem ipsum}
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      \footnotetext[1]{\fullcite{some:source}}
      \begin{figure}[H]
          \centering
          \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
          \caption[Stats Online Privacy]{tats Online Privacy\footnotemark}
      \end{figure}
      \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\footfullcite{some:source}

      \newpage
      \bibliography{\jobname}


      \bibliographystyle{jurabib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will try it out and tell you if it works.

Comment: Oh, some Ansatz ;-)

Comment: @samcarter I tried it and it works fine but the footnote number does not increase. The footnote before the image was 9 and the footnote inside the image is also 9. How do I solve this http://imgur.com/a/oWqv3

Comment: @Curunir `\addtocounter{footnote}{1}`